# Bootstrap 3 carousel-indicators size

Tags: carousel

I am asking that i have added carousel-indicators by using Bootstrap3.and my carousel-indicator looking like rectangle shape.
I have wrote the code as i given below.

```
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="image/1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image/2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image/3.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image/4.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image/5.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image/6.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="image/7.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>

        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>

        </a>

    </div><!--closing carousel-->
```

And I Wanted my Carousel-indicator look like smaller dot.

Answer (score 0):

you can draw SVG figures to use for your carousel controls, you can add an event listener to literally anything to control your carousel.
`<circle cx="25" cy="75" r="20"/>` Play around with the size of it, you can assign it color or other attributes as you would any other HTML element.